# Wordpress login showing a 500 Internal Server Error but front-end works fine

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to access the dashboard/login of my wordpress site (www.example.com/wp-admin) I get a 500 Internal Server Error. However the front-end of the website is showing no errors and working fine. Using Wordpress 4.3 disabled plugins no change.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: It can be any number of things. Check the server's error log and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: 'Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden' - Is all that is in the logs

Comment: Try to add `Options +FollowSymLinks` at  the top of your htaccess

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate on the technical level, that was unclear about what you were asking. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue on a particular page then there must be some php fatal error. To find out the error in this case please check error log corresponding to you domain/virtual host instance.

- Try php linting on wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php.
- Try disabling all plugins or disabling random plugin one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes It also causes for corrupted .htaccess file. I think this post from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/ can help you. Because previously it solves my problem.